# Can "carve into" be used figuratively?

Tags: phrase-meaning, figurative-language

The expression ***carve (something) into (something)*** means, according to [Free dictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/carve+into):

> to create a carved object by sculpturing raw material OR to use a knife or other tool to carve a block of some material, typically wood, into a desired shape.
>
> - e.g. Ken ***carved*** the apple ***into*** a tiny snowman.

My question is, can it be used figuratively to say

> The afflictions he went through ***carved*** him ***into*** an insightful author.

Is this use correct?

Comment: You _could_ use it, but it would be a rather startling, unconventional metaphor.

Comment: We do often use metaphoric ***sculpted, moulded*** and ***honed,*** for erxample, with something of this sense, but ***carved*** would normally be considered at least "quirky". A very unwise choice for a non-native speaker, I'd have thought.

Comment: By "at least quirky" do you mean "almost creepy"?

Comment: Nothing so exotic! Just ***very unusual*** - so if your readers knew or suspected that you weren't a native speaker, they'd be more likely to dismiss the usage as "beginner's mistake" rather than "startlingly fresh poetic imagery".

Comment: One problem with carved is the image that the afflictions were chopping bits off him.

Comment: @mdewey: Can you "fashion someone into something" without chopping bits off him?

Comment: In the figurative sense you mean here I would have thought so. If you undergo psychotherapy after your afflictions it might transform you into a stronger person but you do not lose anything thereby.